# Включение стандартного хэдэра в свой хэдэр

Tags: c++

Имеется небольшой многофайловый код и свой хэдэр к нему. При этом в коде использутся функции принимающие в качестве аргумента ссылку на `vector`. Чтобы включить прототипы этих функций в мой хэдэрфайл нужно добавить строку `#include <vector>`, но в этом случае получается, что если в файле есть строки

```
#include <vector>
#include "my_header.h"
```

то хэдэр `vector` включается в файл дважды. Есть ли в этом проблема и как этого избежать?

Comment: Проблемы никакой нет, *содержимое* этого файла будет включено только один раз, так как в нем есть include guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная библиотека написана профессионалами :)

В ней это предусмотрено, не волнуйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma once
```

в начале файла и файлы будут подключаться только 1 раз